# How do one show that the Pauli Matrices together with the Unit matrix form a basis in the space of complex 2 x 2 matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

In other words, show that a complex 2 x 2 Matrix can in a unique way be written as
$$
M = \lambda _ 0 I+\lambda _1 \sigma _ x + \lambda _2 \sigma _y + \lambda _ 3 \sigma_z 
$$

If$$M = \Big(\begin{matrix}
  m_{11} & m_{12} \\
  m_{21} & m_{22}
 \end{matrix}\Big)= \lambda _ 0 I+\lambda _1 \sigma _ x + \lambda _2 \sigma _y + \lambda _ 3 \sigma_z $$

I get the following equations 
$$
m_{11}=\lambda_0+\lambda_3 \\ m_{12}=\lambda_1-i\lambda_2 \\ m_{21}=\lambda_1+i\lambda_2 \\ m_{22}=\lambda_0-\lambda_3
$$

Comment: Take a matrix with all entries populated and write it as each single entry multiplying a matrix having $1$ in that place and $0$ elsewhere. Then group the similar ones and you will end up with 4 linearly independent matrices, exactly the above.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. Could you explain what you mean in terms of equations?

Comment: Since the Pauli matrices and the identity are hermitian, you can only obtain an hermitian 2x2matrix by combining them. Taking the coefficients $\lambda_i$ as real numbers, you indeed get real diagonal elements $m_{11}$ and $m_{12}$, and complex conjugate off-diagonal elements $m_{12}$ and $m_{21}$, as expected for an hermitian matrix.

Comment: Well, in order to be a basis they would need to 1) be linearly independent (and they are) 2) any matrix can always be expressed as a linear combination thereof (and the arguments that we mentioned above show that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of all $2\times2$ complex matrices. We also note that dim$(M_2(\mathbb{C}))=4$, because if $M\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and

$M=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        z_{11} & z_{12}\\
        z_{21} & z_{22} \\
      \end{array}
    \right)$, where $z_{ij}\in \mathbb{C}$,

then

$M=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        z_{11} & z_{12}\\
        z_{21} & z_{22} \\
      \end{array}
    \right)=z_{11}\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)+z_{12}\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)+z_{21}\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)+z_{22}\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)$.

The standard *four* **Pauli matrices** are:

$I=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 \\
      \end{array}
    \right),~~ 
\sigma_1=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 1\\
        1 & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right),~~
\sigma_2=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & -i\\
        i & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right),~~
\sigma_3=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & -1 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)$.

It is straightforward to show that these four matrices are linearly independent. This can be done as follows.

Let $c_\mu\in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$c_0I+c_1\sigma_1+c_2\sigma_2+c_3\sigma_3=$ **O** (zero matrix).

This gives

$\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        c_0+c_3 & c_1-ic_2\\
        c_1+ic_2 & c_0-c_3 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)$

which further gives the following solution:
$c_0=c_1=c_1=c_3=0$.

It is left to show that $\{I,\sigma_i\}$ where $i = 1,2,3$ spans $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. And this can accomplished in the following way:

$M=c_0I+c_1\sigma_1+c_2\sigma_2+c_3\sigma_3$ gives

$\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        c_0+c_3 & c_1-ic_2\\
        c_1+ic_2 & c_0-c_3 \\
      \end{array}
    \right)=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        z_{11} & z_{12}\\
        z_{21} & z_{22} \\
      \end{array}
    \right)$

which further gives the following equations:

$c_0+c_3=z_{11},~c_0-c_3=z_{22},~c_1-ic_2=z_{12},~c_1+ic_2=z_{21}$.

Solving these equations, one obtains

$c_0=\frac{1}{2}(z_{11}+z_{22}),~c_1=\frac{1}{2}(z_{12}+z_{21}),~c_2=\frac{1}{2}i(z_{12}-z_{21}),~c_3=\frac{1}{2}(z_{11}-z_{22})$.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the question has already been sufficiently answered, I would like to offer the sketch of another "elegant" proof:

The space of complex $2\times 2$ matrices, denoted $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^8$ via
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
z_{11} & z_{12} \\
z_{21} & z_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
\Re z_{11} &
\Im z_{11} &
\Re z_{12} &
\Im z_{12} &
\Re z_{21} &
\Im z_{21} &
\Re z_{22} &
\Im z_{22}
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\end{equation}
where $\Re$ and $\Im$ denote real and imaginary parts.

Now you want to show that $(I,\sigma_i)$ is a basis of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ as complex vector space, which is equivalent to $(I,\sigma_i, iI,i\sigma_i)$ being a basis of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ as real vector space.

The above isomorphism maps the identity and Pauli matrices like:
\begin{align*}
I &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
1 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
\sigma_1 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
0 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
\sigma_2 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
0 &
0 &
-1 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
\sigma_3 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
-1 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
iI &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
1 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
1
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
i\sigma_1 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
0 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
i\sigma_2 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
0 &
1 &
0 &
-1 &
0 &
0 &
0
\end{pmatrix}^\top\\
i\sigma_3 &\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
1 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
0 &
-1
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\end{align*}
which can trivially be seen to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^8$ as a real vector space.

Therefore, by the property of isomorphisms to map basis to basis vice versa, we are done.

Answer (score 3):

To show that $\{I, \sigma_i\}$ is a base of the complex vector space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices, you need to prove two things:

1. That $\{I, \sigma_i\}$ are [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).
2. That every complex $2 \times 2$ matrix can be written as a combination of $\{I, \sigma_i\}$.

To prove point 1, you need to show that the only four complex numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that

$$a_0 I + a_1 \sigma_1 + a_2 \sigma_2 + a_3 \sigma_3 = 0$$

where $0$ is the [zero matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_matrix), are $a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.

To prove point 2, you need to show that every complex $2 \times 2$ matrix $M$ can be written as

$$M = c_0 I + c_1 \sigma_1 + c_2 \sigma_2 + c_3 \sigma_3 $$

where $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$ are complex numbers. Your equations are correct, but what do you need to show in order to prove 2?

Comment: To show number 2 I need to show that they span the space of complex 2x2 matrices?

Comment: @user2120387 Yes, that is another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @user2120387 What I'm trying to say is that your equations are not wrong, but maybe you need to write them in a different form to prove what you need to prove...

Comment: Since evidently the space of $2\times 2$ complex matrices has dimension $4$, 1 implies 2. You do not have  to prove 2.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Shouldn't we show before that $\{I,\sigma_i\}$ is a basis and then deduce from this that the dimension of the space is $4$? After all, the dimension of a vector space is defined as the cardinality of its bases.

Comment: @valerio92  See my answer...

Answer (score 1):

And yet another answer.

Pauli matrices $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ evidently form a base of the 3-dimensional real vector space of the 2 by 2 traceless Hermitian matrices. Since every Hermitian matrix is the sum of a traceless Hermitian matrix and the real multiple of the identity matrix, $\sigma_1\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ an $I$ together form a base of the 4-dimensional real vector space of the 2 by 2 Hermitian matrices.

Since every complex 2 by 2 matrix can be decomposed to the sum of a Hermitian and an anti-Hermitian matrix, regarding that, $M$ is hermitian if and only if $iM$ is anti-Hermitian, every complex 2 by 2 matrix $M$ can be written as $M=A+iB$ where both $A$ and $B$ is Hermitian. So, there are some unique real numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,b_0,b_1,b_2, b_3$ so that $A=a_0I+\sum_i{a_i\sigma_i}$ and $B=b_0I+\sum_i{b_i\sigma_i}$ hence $M=(a_0+ib_0)I+\sum_i(a_i+ib_i)\sigma_i$ that is, the Pauli matrices and $I$ together expand the complex vector space of the 2 by 2 complex matrices. Since the (complex) dimension of this vector space is 4, they form a base.