# How to prove that every mixed one-qubit state admits a Bloch-sphere representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator, bloch-sphere

A mixed state $\rho$ can be written as

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left(I+r_x\sigma_x+r_y\sigma_y+r_z\sigma_z\right)\qquad\left(\vec{r}:=\left(r_x,r_y,r_z\right)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3; ||\vec{r}||\leq 1\right)$$

according to Nielsen & Chuang in "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" (from 2010) (p. 105).

Does anyone know a reference where this has been proven and not just stated? Thank you!

Comment: It is a about a qubit, no?

Comment: You can prove it yourself... there are three real degrees of freedom of any $2\times 2$ Hermitian trace-one operator, which can uniquely be expressed in terms of $\vec{r}$... or, you can prove that the Pauli matrices are a basis for $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices

Comment: see e.g. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5993/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16411/55, and links therein

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699132/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-of-one-qubit-density-matrix-on-bloch-sphere) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state space of a qubit $\mathscr H\simeq \mathbb C^2$ is two-dimensional. The Pauli matrices $\{\sigma_i\}_{i=0,\ldots,3}$ form a basis for the real vector space of hermitian $2\times2$ matrices of dimension $2^2=4$, cf. e.g.[this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629565/positive-matrices-representation/629575#629575) and the links therein. As such, any hermitian matrix can be expanded in this basis set.
A density operator is a positive operator (and hence hermitian) of unit trace and you can thus expand it in the basis of Pauli matrices:

$$ \rho = \sum\limits_{i=0}^3 r_i \, \sigma_i \quad , \tag{1}$$
with $r_i \in \mathbb R .$

Now use the positivity and trace condition to find conditions for the expansion coefficients. For example, you can write $\rho$ in a the basis of eigenvectors of $\sigma_3$ and diagonalize it. Then you'll see that $\rho$ is a density matrix if and only if
$$r_0=\frac{1}{2}\quad \text{and}\quad\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 r_i^2 \leq \frac{1}{4} \tag{2} $$holds.

Comment: By chance: do you know a reference (book) that has comments on the said basis property of pauli matrices? Thank you!

Comment: @manuel459 Sorry, no. But I think this is a fairly well-known fact, so there should be some things online, perhaps Wikipedia, yet I don't know. Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292102/how-do-one-show-that-the-pauli-matrices-together-with-the-unit-matrix-form-a-bas) help?

Comment: I mean this fact is stated in some books (cf. Preskill's lecture notes) but not proven.

Comment: Stated is enough in this minor case. I'll take a look at it! Do you know which number? As far as it is something I could "officially" cite it works perfect. Thank you again.

Comment: @manuel459 Chapter 2.3.2 in his lecture notes from 1998. Also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) this fact is mentioned several times. You might have a look there. But they don't cite a source as far as I see.

Comment: Thank you very much!