# How to write an arbitrary qubit density operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, bloch-sphere

Physics noob here: I am reading the Wikipedia on Density Matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix), and in the section labeled "Pure and mixed states", it states

> "An arbitrary state for a qubit can be written as a linear combination of the Pauli matrices, which provide a basis for $2\times2$ self-adjoint matrices:
> $$\rho = \frac{1}{2}(I +r_x\sigma_x + r_y\sigma_y + r_z\sigma_z)."$$

My question is, how is this arbitrary? Couldn't I cook up some density operator that you can't write using this equation? i.e something like ~$\begin{pmatrix}i&i\\i&i\end{pmatrix}$ (not including normalization). What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to prove that every mixed one-qubit state admits a Bloch-sphere representation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699078/2451)

Comment: Possibly related: [Necessary and sufficient conditions for operator on $\mathbb C^2$
to be a density matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699132/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density matrix has to be self-adjoint by definition and your example is not self-adjoint, or respectively, hermitian, i.e. $\rho \neq \rho^\dagger$.
As you wrote, the Pauli matrices provide a basis for self-adjoint matrices, so therefore you can write any self-adjoint matrix as a linear combination of the Pauli-matrices, similarly to how you can write any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by a linear combination of the canonical basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$.

Comment: This self-adjointness is the point I missed. Thanks!