# Do Bloch sphere rotations span $SU(2)$ (up to a global phase)?

Tags: quantum-information, group-theory, bloch-sphere

It is well known that the Pauli group $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$ spans the group of $2\times2$ unitary matrices, $SU(2)$, for example see this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292102/).

A general Bloch sphere rotation by an angle $\alpha$ about an arbitrary axis, $\hat{n}$ is given by:

$$R_{\hat{n}}\left(\alpha\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)I-i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\left(n_x X+n_y Y+n_z Z\right)$$

Is it true, that up to a global phase, Bloch sphere rotations span $SU(2)$?

If so, can it be proved without using group theory and abstract algebra?

Comment: actually technically the Pauli group has $8$ elements: $\pm \mathbb{I},\pm X,\pm Y,\pm Z$.  See https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528006

Comment: All you need to do is to show that any SU(2) matrix has the form $R_{\hat n}$ so write the most general SU(2) matrix and find the coefficients $n_i$ and $\alpha$ using trace orthogonality of the Pauli matrices…

Comment: $SU(2)$ is not a vector space, so it isn't the span of anything. The four matrices you've given span all of $\mathbb C^{2\times2},$ which includes $SU(2)$ but also a lot of other junk. $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is a vector space and is spanned by just $X,Y,Z.$ The map $\exp:\mathfrak{su}(2)\to SU(2)$ surjects, and your $R$ should be explainable as interpreting $\hat n,a$ as a element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and then exponentiating.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/204090/). **(2)** [Why is there this relationship between quaternions and Pauli matrices?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/).

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174562/2451